# Question about ring homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a ring homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f$ sends $x$ to $3$. I want to find $f(x^3+2)$.
My attempt is, since $f$ is a homomorphism
$$f(x^3+2)=f^3(x)+f(2)=27+f(2)$$ but what is $f(2)$?

Comment: A ring homomorphism sends the identity to the identity, hence $f(1)=1$, so $f(2)=f(1+1)=\,...$

Comment: @quasi A ring-with-identity homomorphism sends the identity to the identity; that can't  be literally true for a  ring homomorphism, since a ring need not have an  identity. (And in fact if $R$ is a ring with identity and $f:R\to R$ iis defined by $f(x)=0$ then $f$ _is_ a ring homomorphism.) In this example it's not hard to _prove_ that $f(1)=1$, in spite of that (and without assuming that we really havve a ring-with-identity homomorphism): $3=f(x)=f(1x)=3f(1)$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: Many authors require, as part of the definition of ring, the existence of a multiplicative identity $1$, and for such rings, they require, as part of the definition of homomorphism, that a ring homomorphism sends $1$ to $1$. But I agree, if rings are not required to have a multiplicative identity, then your argument nicely avoids the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $f(2) = f(1 + 1) = f(1) + f(1) = 1 + 1 = 2$, so $f(x^3 + 2) = 29$.